ubuntu 22.04 show : Unable to locate package gcc-12
When I install gcc
apt install --reinstall gcc-12 -y

It report error:  Unable to locate package gcc-12
How should a problem like this one be solved?

Does this answer your question? How do I enable the "Universe" repository?

A quick look (using CLI) shows gcc-12 | 12-20220319-1ubuntu1  | jammy/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x, do do you have universe enabled?

Does this answer your question? How do I restore the default repositories?
